# validate a base field in a particular content type

Tags: 8, nodes, plugins

Since `title` field is considered as base field  in Drupal 8, I opted `hook_entity_base_field_info_alter` to add validation to it. But when I look at that hook.

```
hook_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type)
```

It doesn't holds a `$bundle` argument. So I couldn't add a validation for title field of a particular node type. How can I override it to be node type specific?

Answer (score 3):

Base fields are by definition not bundle specific, you can't add something for a specific bundle in that hook.

However, what you can do is save it as a base field override. See how [NodeTypeForm::save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeTypeForm.php/function/NodeTypeForm%3A%3Asave/8) saves different default values and labels for base fields as base field overrides.

Answer (score 0):

You can check too node title validation https://www.drupal.org/project/node_title_validation

This module check unique titles, max & min characters and blacklist words.